# What are the scoping rules of a `<template repeat>`

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Should bindings created inside a template `repeat` require an associated property on the polymer element, I thought they were bound to the array items of an `ObservableList`?

Inside my template is the following code:

```
<polymer-element name="event-details">
  <template>
    <!-- etc -->
    <template repeat="{{artist in event.artist}}">
      <artist-card artist="{{artist}}">
    </template>
    <!-- etc -->
  </template>
  <!-- etc -->
</polymer-element>
```

And my element definition looks like

```
@CustomTag('event-details')
class EventDetails {
   /* etc */
   @published
   api.Event get event => readValue(#event);
   set event(api.Event event) => writeValue(#event, value);
   /* etc */
}
```

When I create the element, I get the error

```
"EventDetails has no attribute `artist`"
```

but I assumed that the `artist` in the `<template repeat>` should only exist inside that template's scope. There is no value in having the `{{artist}}` on the element's definition, as it will only ever point to the last element in the template's children.

`artists` is an `ObservableList` on the `api.Event` object, although it is defined without using polymer.

Comment: Could you try to rename the local variable to `repeat="{{a in event.artist}}"` and `artist="{{a}}"`?

Comment: `Error evaluating expression 'a': Class 'EventDetails' has no instance setter 'a='.`

Comment: I would try a simple field next `@published api.Event event;` instead of the readValue/writeValue.

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error.

Comment: Changing it to  `<template repeat="{{a in event.artists}}">{{a}}</template>` removes the error though, so it could have something to do with the fact that `artist` is `@published` in `artist-card`.

Comment: And changing the `artist` in `ArtistCard` to a simple property (instead of `read/writeValue` also solves the problem.

Since the type is already observable, is there any reason to use `read/writeValue`? Is a simple property just a one-time binding? I'm not sure of the mechanics of all that.

Comment: From what I gathered it's to more exactly mimic timing behavior with the dart2js build output. I didn't yet run into such issues and have never seen it mentioned by others, therefore I stick with the simple field/getter/setter until I bump my nose. Would be great if you could create a bug report at http://dartbug.com to get this fixed with readValue/writeValue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple property (field/getter/setter) instead of readValue/writeValue.

Comment: It's a solution, but not a particularly satisfying one. I've run into problems where bindings don't update the value of a simple property in the past (particularly when dealing with `<input>`s) and I've found that readValue/writeValue usually fixes whatever problem I'm having, so I default to that for everything. I will file that bug though.